# Code to perform formulas to all excel files in a folder not running?

Tags: excel, vba

=I have a code that performs a series of calculations to all Excel (.xls) files in a folder destination and places a specific number in specified cells (G2, H2, I2, M2 and O1). The only issue is the code does not respond when I click run. It doesn't give an error. Any ideas where I went wrong here?

```
Sub Code()

    Dim file As String
    Dim wbResults As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myPath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    myPath = "C:\Location\"

    file = Dir$(myPath & "*.xls*")

    While (Len(file) > 0)
        Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & file, UpdateLinks:=0)

        With wbResults.Worksheets(Split(file, ".")(0))
            i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

            With .Range("G2")
                .Formula = "=0"
            End With

            With .Range("G3:G" & i)
                .Formula = "=SQRT(((E3-E2)^2)+((F3-F2)^2))"
            End With

            With .Range("H2")
                .Formula = "=1"
            End With

            With .Range("H3:H" & i)
                .Formula = "=G3+H2"
            End With

            With .Range("I2")
                .Formula = "=1"
            End With

            With .Range("I3")
                .Formula = "=IF(D3>=SUM($I$2:I2*2.5+$O$1),1,0)"
            End With

            With .Range("I4:I" & i)
                .Formula = "=IF(D3>=SUM($I$3:I3)*2.5+$O$1,1,0)"
            End With

            With .Range("J2:K" & i)
                .Formula = "=IF($I2=1,D2,J1)"
            End With

            With .Range("K2:K" & i)
                .Formula = "=IF($I2=1,H2,K1)"
            End With

            With .Range("L2:L" & i)
                .Formula = "=IF(I2=1,(J2-J1)/(K2-K1),"")"
            End With

            With .Range("M2")
                .Formula = "=0"
            End With

            With .Range("M3:M" & i)
                .Formula = "=IF(L3="",M2,L3)"
            End With

            With .Range("O1")
                .Formula = "=177.5"
            End With

        End With

        wbResults.Close SaveChanges:=True
        file = Dir
    Wend

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out these lines for debugging purposes.  Once fixed, un-comment them.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

---

I see a couple problems.

- If a file is not found with `.xls` extension, nothing will happen.
- Everywhere you have a string in formula `""` you have to double quote like this `""""`

  ```
  With .Range("L2:L" & i)
      .Formula = "=IF(I2=1,(J2-J1)/(K2-K1),"""")"
  End With
  ```
- You are missing an equals sign before the `IF` on these equations

  ```
  With .Range("J2:K" & i)
      .Formula = "=IF($I2=1,D2,J1)"
  End With

  With .Range("K2:K" & i)
     .Formula = "=IF($I2=1,H2,K1)"
  End With
  ```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like the double quotations was the issue. I noticed the equal sign shortly after posting.